# child project in main codeIgniter project is not working, not found error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have CodeIgniter project and I put another codeIgniter project named "admin"inside that project

structure looks like this

```
    codeIgniter project
       admin (this is another codeIgniter project)
       application
       public
       system
       user_guide
       vendor
       few php and htaccess files here
```

I access normal project like example.com and to access admin project I work like **example.com/admin** these all are working fine, but now I added another codeIgniter project inside main project "api"
it does not work.

Now structure looks like this

```
    codeIgniter project
       admin (this is codeIgniter project)
       api (this project does not work, url issue)
       application
       public
       system
       user_guide
       vendor
       few php and htaccess files here
```

Comment: i did changes in config file , but still getting not found error for "api" project , while "admin" project is working fine

Comment: api project is working good on localhost but not live

Comment: Nesting a project within a project is not a good idea. That's an almost certain recipe for.multiple code and config, routing, a, etc conflicts. My advice would be to add functionality from your admin project to your original one or to separate both projects entirely. Why overcomplicate yourself?